# Rails - How can I use has_scope with collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, has-scope

I'm new to rails and I'm using the has_scope gem to help me filter a list to display as a table. I have the has_scope gem setup fine and working for basic parameters (search string, etc.)

How can I get has_scope to recognize the parameters passed in from a collection_select?

I'm doing...

```
<%= collection_select(:param_val, "company_name", Food.all, :company_name, :company_name, {}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

Which passes the URL as

```
http://localhost:3000/foods?utf8=%E2%9C%93&param_val%5Bcompany_name%5D=McDonalds&commit=Search
```

And it doesn't filter, just returns the whole list. If I manually adjust the URL to...

```
http://localhost:3000/foods?utf8=%E2%9C%93&company_name%5D=McDonalds&commit=Search
```

Then it works fine. So I need to pass ONLY the company_name value, not the entire hash name, but I'm struggling on what I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this issue, I wasn't able to solve it using the has_scope gem. In my controller I just did this instead...

```
  if  @company_filter_list.any?
    @filtered_foods = @all_foods.companies(@company_filter_list)  
  end
```